# Can I compute a VAR Model and then work on only one OLS equation?

Tags: least-squares, vector-autoregression, granger-causality, ardl, gretl

Good morning,
I'm trying to estimate a VAR model between six variables and one of them is the price of copper.

What I'm interested in is only the equation of the copper prices and i'm running a VAR just to understand which variables "Granger-Cause" copper prices.
However, whatever the number of lags I choose, if I test for autocorrelation, it's always present.

Therefore, I thought: "If I'm interested in just one equation, can't I compute an OLS regression using Copper Prices as dependent variable and check the correctness of this single equation?"

If doing so, I immediately find that just by using three lags there's no autocorrelation and the model is overall correctly specified, with no multicollinearity or heteroskedasticity.

So, in conclusion, instead of computing a VAR model, wouldn't be the same to compute and OLS regression and then test for each variables and it's lag if jointly are different from zero, so basically compute a Granger Causality test manually?

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Working with a single equation form a VAR model is fine. On its own, it would be called autoregressive distributed lag (ARDL) model. (In a way, ARDL is more flexible than a VAR, as you can choose the lag lengths individually for every variable in the system.) You do not need the other equations to figure out what variables Granger-cause copper price. The equation with the copper price as the dependent variable is enough for that. Also, for model diagnostics, analyzing the single equation for copper price is enough.

Comment: Thank you Richard! I've another question. I'm struggling to understand whether to use non-stationary variables or not. If I were estimating a VAR model, I would have used the Toda and Yamamoto approach and so, non-starionary variables. However, since I am estimating a single OLS regression (ARDL model as you mentioned), what should I use?

Comment: Moreover, what if I'd be interest in the IRF plots? Can I run the VAR model using the lags of the ARDL (supposing I choose the same number of lags for each variable) and then plot the IRF and take the information only on the effect on the copper price?

Comment: @Ricter, you can define IRF for a VAR and IRF for an ARDL. These will be different. If you have a VAR, IRF reflects how shocks propagate through an entire system. Meanwhile, in an ARDL the channels through which shocks propagate are fewer in number.

Comment: Sure. Thanks! What about the use of non-stationary variables as I mentioned before?

Comment: @Ricter, if I remember correctly, Dave Giles has some great blog posts on that. Check them out [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=dave+giles+ardl+models). Let us know in the comments what you have found :)

Comment: I found something interesting. However, Giles is not using ARDL to test for Granger causality but rather to examine the presence of long or short-run relationships and I'm struggling to connect both concepts.

Comment: @Ricter, if you have integrated and cointegrated variables, perhaps the Toda-Yamamoto procedure described in another post by Dave Giles is the better way to go. But of course there is the problem with autocorrelated residuals. If no lag produces well-behaved residuals, perhaps there are some additional things going on (seasonality, some one-off events, structural changes, ...) that need to be accounted for? Or perhaps your series are very long so that even tiny autocorrelations are statistically significant? In the latter case I would not worry too much and just pick a reasonable lag order.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151274/discussion-between-ricter-and-richard-hardy).